# Is there an alternative to using the default android emulator?

Tags: android

Is there a better way to test apk files without actually having to buy an Android phone?

I have to test several apk files and i don't want to use the Eclipse to do this as it would be a lot of downloading just for testing as i don't even want to code.

I am looking for an application which would provide an interface which would ask me which version of Android do i want to run and what screen size do i want and then install the apk for me that i want to test?
Is there such a software available?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Eclipse to run the emulator. You can simply download the android SDK [HERE](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). After you've extracted the SDK, run the file "android" in the tools folder (in linux at least),  download which platforms you want to use (1.6, 2.1, etc) and create an emulator. It's fairly simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

Many phone makers offer such a service...

Here's one to start you out:

http://developer.motorola.com/testing/

-I_Artist

Comment: it was a good suggestion but turns out they (motorolla) tests our apps for us and then gives us the result ie statistics. This does not serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you are looking for. I never used it myelf though.  The reviews seem to be ok as well.  not sure if you can choose what api's you want to use though.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/download-google-android-emulator/